# Inner Joi me repite datos en una consulta

Tags: sql, join

Al momento de hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
select M.id, M.nombre, M.especie, M.raza, d.nombre 
from mascotas M 
inner join (select d.nombre, d.id,d.idMascota from duenos d) d on M.id = d.idMascota 
where M.idUsuario = 1
```

Me genera los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que el registro con el id 1 sea una sola columna y el nombre sea varios, pero sin alterar el registro 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo obtener esto, pero en el campo con el id 2, obtener el registro original es decir oso

Comment: ¿qué gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: no entiendo cual es el resultado que esperas obtener, por otro lado ¿por qué en `inner join` metes una sub consulta?

Comment: utilizo sql server

Comment: Espero obtener que el registro con el id 2 tenga su nombre y el registro con el id 1 tenga varios

Comment: Es decir que en el mismo renglón donde dice: **pancho** salgan en la misma celda los nombres de los dueños?

Comment: no, que salgan varios.

Comment: no se entiende entonces lo que buscas obtener, te sugiero editar y colocar un ejemplo de lo que buscas obtener

Comment: Lo que pides es que, para aquellas mascotas que tengan más de un dueño, en la columna `nombre` del final salga *varios* pero en el que solo haya uno, salga el nombre del dueño ¿no?

Answer (score 2):

Vas a tener que agrupar los datos. Pero si el nombre solo es uno, entonces el máximo y el mínimo serán iguales y puedes tomar cualquiera de los dos. De otra forma, solo muestras la cadena 'varios'.

```
SELECT M.id, 
    M.nombre, 
    M.especie, 
    M.raza, 
    CASE WHEN MAX(d.nombre) = MIN(d.nombre) THEN MAX(d.nombre) ELSE 'varios' END AS nombre
FROM mascotas M 
INNER JOIN duenos d ON M.id = d.idMascota 
WHERE M.idUsuario = 1
GROUP BY M.id, 
    M.nombre, 
    M.especie, 
    M.raza;
```